# embulk - communication_link_failure

Tags: mysql, google-cloud-platform, google-bigquery

I want to ask about how to solve communication_link_failure error when I migrate mysql data to bigquery by using embulk. the table which I want to migrate is more than 1GB. I think that size is reason for error return.

How can I set my embulk config.yml file? Or how to migrate big table by using embulk.

Answer (score 0):

`communication_link_failure` probably, Embulk can't connect MySQL server. I recommend you check the network setting.

If you can't solve the issue, Could you tell me the following?

- Embulk version:
- Java version: java -version
- OS version
- Embulk config (remove sensitive information)
- Error message (Embulk run result)